# OpenCV Caffe C++ - Forwarding multiple Images

Tags: c++, opencv, caffe

In the tutorial listed on the OPENCV website:

http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html

It seems we can easily forward single images through the network. I would however like to forward a batch of images through. This is possible in python but I have not found any C++ example online. I would like to avoid using a for loop to iterate and forward each image.

Comment: in `dnn::Blob::fromImages(img)` pass a `vector<Mat>`

Comment: turns out i just used the caffe c++ api instead. the dnn module is severly unoptimized